# call JavaScript function from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have this JavaScript code in an ASPX page

```
<script>
    function show_modal(statut) 
    {
        if (statut == true)
        {
            $(function () 
            {
                $('#modal_success').modal('show')
            })
        }
        else
        {
            $(function ()
            {
                $('#modal_fail').modal('show')
            })
        }
     }
</script>
```

That shows an modalpopup which I like to launch from my code behind.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
if (resultat)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "show_modal(true);");
            
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "show_modal(false);");
        }
```

but I can't figure out why!

Comment: may be something wrong with my Javascript code ? i'm using twiter bootstrap framework.

Comment: Haven't you missed the ; from the `.modal('show')` lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) requires you to wrap the call in a `<script>` tag (or use the [other overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) which allows you to specify if script tags are added)

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", 
                "<script>show_modal(true);</script>");
```

or

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", 
                "show_modal(true);", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script, true);
```

Comment: Isn't the ScriptManager [meant for controls in an UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method** => it should work and for more check the Error console for tracing your issue.